# Searching markers with Leaflet.Control.Search from drop down list

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet

I use [Leaflet.Control.Search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) for searching markers by GeoJSON features and it works OK. Now I have to type first letters to find marker, but I want to choose them from drop down list with all markers in it. Is it way to do it?

Comment: Is that a feature of this control? If not, you'll have to modify the source to add it yourself.

Comment: I'm searching markers by their names, included in my GeoJSON like string values. Now I have to type letters «c», «i» etc. to find the place with name «City» for example. After I enter some characters, the plugin gives me short list with names corresponding my query. This is a plugin works by default. My purpose is choosing the name from entire drop down list with all names instead of typing a marker name.

Comment: But is this a feature of the component? Refer to the documentation provided to see if this is possible. If it isn't, you'll have to modify the component yourself to accomplish this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a dropdown list with all your markers, you are better off creating a custom control rather than trying to modify Leaflet.Control.Search. Creating a control with a `select` element that contains all your markers is a little complicated, but certainly far simpler than tweaking the code of someone else's finished project.

Start by creating an empty control:

```
var selector = L.control({
  position: 'topright'
});
```

To put content within the control, you can use the control's `.onAdd` method. Create a container div for the control using `L.DomUtil.create`, which in this context will automatically assign the class `leaflet-control`, allowing any content within the div to display on the map and behave like a control should behave. Then create a `select` element within the div. Give it a default option if you want. Most importantly, give it an `id`, so that you can refer to it later:

```
selector.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mySelector');
  div.innerHTML = '<select id="marker_select"><option value="init">(select item)</option></select>';
  return div;
};
```

Now that the control knows what to do when added to the map, go ahead and add it:

```
selector.addTo(map);
```

To add all your markers as options in the selector, you can use the [`.eachLayer` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer), which iterates through all the markers in the group and calls a function for each. For each layer, create an `option` element and append it to the `select` element, using the `id` assigned above. Assuming that you have created a GeoJSON layer called `markerLayer`, which has a property called `STATION` that you want to use as the option text, it would look like this:

```
markerLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
  optionElement.innerHTML = layer.feature.properties.STATION;
  optionElement.value = layer._leaflet_id;
  L.DomUtil.get("marker_select").appendChild(optionElement);
});
```

Here, we're relying on the fact that each layer gets assigned a unique internal id number, `_leaflet_id`, when created. We set each option's `value` attribute to the corresponding layer's `_leaflet_id`, so that when the option is selected, we have a way to access the marker.

Finally, to get the control to actually do something when you select one of the options, add some event listeners, using the `id` of the selector element:

```
var marker_select = L.DomUtil.get("marker_select");
L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'click', function(e) {
  L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
});
L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'change', changeHandler);
```

The `click` listener with the `stopPropagation` method is to prevent clicks on the selector from propagating through to the map if they overlap with the map pane, which could immediately unselect the layer you are trying to highlight. The `change` listener will run a handler function, which you can set to do anything you want. Here, I've set it to open the popup for a marker when its corresponding option is selected:

```
function changeHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.value == "init") {
    map.closePopup();
  } else {
    markerLayer.getLayer(e.target.value).openPopup();
  }
}
```

And that's it! Here is an example fiddle with all this working together:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ev3kojon/

**EDIT:**

If you are using the MarkerCluster plugin, you can modify the change handler function to work with clustered markers using the [`.zoomToShowLayer` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-group-methods):

```
function changeHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.value == "init") {
    map.closePopup();
  } else {
    var selected = markerLayer.getLayer(e.target.value);
    markerClusterLayer.zoomToShowLayer(selected, function() {
      selected.openPopup();
    })
  }
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/oqk6u0sL/

(I also updated the original code and example to use the `.getLayer` method rather than `._layers[e.target.value]`, because this is a cleaner way to access the marker based on its id)

Comment: Everything works OK, but I have one more problem. In my case there are many markers located in a quite small area: 
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/0fqqur22/1/
That's why I use markercluster plugin, it puts markers into groups well:
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/zbpryd8g/5/
But when I try to combine your amazing code with that plugin, something are going wrong...
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/Ltgna2zw/22/
Search doesn't work with markers combined in a clusters. Markers don't come together correctly. Can you say me what I do wrong?

Comment: In line 25 of the fiddle, `layer.bindPopup(popup).addTo(map)`, you are adding each marker to the map when you bind the popup, so the markers are added twice - once individually and then again as part of the markerCluster. Change the line to `layer.bindPopup(popup)`, and it should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks again, after I corrected that line, clustering became OK:
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/Ltgna2zw/23/
But the selection from drop down list doesn't work at zoom levels, where markers are in clusters. It also doesn't work at high zoom levels, if selected marker isn't in current screen (i.e. it doesn't skip to marker outside current screen, like in case without clustering). Is it way to fix that problem?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Fortunately, the marker cluster plugin has a method to zoom in to show a single marker, called `zoomToShowLayer`. I'll update the answer with an example soon.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a way to slightly modify Leaflet-search plugin so that it shows the full list of markers when user clicks on the magnifier button (i.e. when user expands the search control).

As if the search was triggered for 0 typed letter.

Using option `minLength: 0` without modifying the plugin code does not trigger a search without typing unfortunately.

```js
L.Control.Search.mergeOptions({
  minLength: 0 // Show full list when no text is typed.
});

L.Control.Search.include({

  _handleKeypress: function(e) {

    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 27: //Esc
        this.collapse();
        break;
      case 13: //Enter
        if (this._countertips == 1)
          this._handleArrowSelect(1);
        this._handleSubmit(); //do search
        break;
      case 38: //Up
        this._handleArrowSelect(-1);
        break;
      case 40: //Down
        this._handleArrowSelect(1);
        break;
      case 37: //Left
      case 39: //Right
      case 16: //Shift
      case 17: //Ctrl
        //case 32://Space
        break;
      case 8: //backspace
      case 46: //delete
        this._autoTypeTmp = false;
        if (this._collapsing) { // break only if collapsing.
          break;
        }
      default: //All keys

        this._doSearch(); // see below
    }
  },

  // externalized actual search process so that we can trigger it after control expansion.
  _doSearch: function() {
    if (this._input.value.length)
      this._cancel.style.display = 'block';
    else
      this._cancel.style.display = 'none';

    if (this._input.value.length >= this.options.minLength) {
      var that = this;

      clearTimeout(this.timerKeypress);
      this.timerKeypress = setTimeout(function() {

        that._fillRecordsCache();

      }, this.options.delayType);
    } else
      this._hideTooltip();
  },

  expand: function(toggle) {
    toggle = typeof toggle === 'boolean' ? toggle : true;
    this._input.style.display = 'block';
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this._container, 'search-exp');
    if (toggle !== false) {
      this._input.focus();
      this._map.on('dragstart click', this.collapse, this);
    }
    this.fire('search_expanded');
    this._doSearch(); // Added to trigger a search when expanding the control.
    return this;
  },

  collapse: function() {
    this._hideTooltip();
    this._collapsing = true; // added to prevent showing tooltip when collapsing
    this.cancel();
    this._collapsing = false; // added to prevent showing tooltip when collapsing
    this._alert.style.display = 'none';
    this._input.blur();
    if (this.options.collapsed) {
      this._input.style.display = 'none';
      this._cancel.style.display = 'none';
      L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._container, 'search-exp');
      if (this.options.hideMarkerOnCollapse) {
        this._markerLoc.hide();
      }
      this._map.off('dragstart click', this.collapse, this);
    }
    this.fire('search_collapsed');
    return this;
  }

});
```

Include this code in your JavaScript before instantiating `L.Control.Search`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/190/

The big drawback of this solution is that the list of markers is built within the map container. As such, if it is too big, it will be cropped on the bottom, whereas a true select (drop-down) input would "overflow" beyond the container, as in nathansnider's solution.